# Avoid multiple use of a Filter in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to avoid using the same filter on the same collection multiple times in AngularJS application.

What is the correct way to do it:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
 <ul ng-init="(person in people|filter:{show:true}) as myPeople" ng-if="myPeople.length>0">
    <h4>My People</h4>
    <li ng-repeat="person in myPeople">{{person.name}}; display: {{person.show}};
  </ul>
</div>
```

[CODE PEN](http://codepen.io/serhio/pen/RRGYPd?editors=1010)

When I use `(person in people|filter:{show:true}) as myPeople` I try to use an alias in order to not repeat the same filter`{show:true}` everywhere...

Comment: can you detail all the filtering that you want to do, i only see one filtering here.

Comment: I try do not repeat `(person in people|filter:{show:true})` everywhere

Comment: If you need to show the same filtered version of a list frequently, the most performant way is to construct a filtered version of the myPeople array inside the controller and include *that* in your template.

Comment: yes, but if I have different filters in different combinations... creating for each of them a variable could bring some mess in the code, isn't it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it something like this:

```
<div ng-init="myPeople = (people | filter:{show:true})">
  <div ng-if="myPeople.length>0">
    <h4> My People</h4>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="person in myPeople">
        {{person.name}}; age: {{person.age}}; show: {{person.show}};
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used ng-init and ng-if on the same element! ) is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, you need to have ngIf inside, because due to very high priority it's executed before ngInit.